# Java Return Type And Method Failure

Tags: java, methods, static-methods, void, return-type

[This](https://wiki.ittc.ku.edu/ittc/EECS168:Homework3) is my assignment.

```
public class Fighter {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String name;
    int hitPoints;
    int defenseLevel;
    int attackSpeed;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    
    public static void hitPoints(){
        int hitPoints;
        do{
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is the hit points for the fighter");
            hitPoints=input.nextInt();
            return hitPoints;
        }while (hitPoints<=50);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that looping it is completely wrong. I get an error `Syntax error on token "void", @ expected"`.

I also tried it with different types such as `int` and `double`. No dice.

The assignment says to only use one void method:

> Write two methods inside of Fighter Class;
>
> ```
> public void input()
> public boolean attack(Fighter opponent)
> ```

However, I couldn't figure out how to do it with one so I was going to use 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. You need to have `hitPoints()` method outside the main. You can't nest it inside the `main()` method.

And also, the return type of your `hitPoints()` is void, you have return statements in the method. Change the return type to `int`, so that you can return an `int` value from this method to the calling method.

```
public static int hitPoints(){
```

Also, since its a `do-while` loop(exit check loop), you don't need the default return. Instead initialize your `hitPoints` to `0` by default.

```
public static int hitPoints() { // return type is int, to return an int value
    int hitPoints = 0; // default value
    do {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the hit points for the fighter");
        hitPoints = input.nextInt();
        return hitPoints;
    } while (hitPoints <= 50);
    // return 0; // not required, as its a do-while loop above
}
```

Comment: You are wonderful, thank you so much for answering, and so quickly. I learn so much here and people are so thankful. I was brutally frustrated and had to walk away for a few minutes. It's really nice to come back and have a plan of attack.

Answer (score 0):

Two prblems:

Firstly, you are trying to encapsulate a method inside a method that is not legal. Move your `hitPoints` outside main `method`.

Secondly you are trying to return an integer value from your `hitPoints` method but that does not return anything as per its definition:

```
public static void hitPoints()
```

So either change your `hitPoints` method signature to return an `int` or remove the `return` statement from the method as mentioned here:

```
 return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, for some reason, I was thinking that everything had to be inside the main method, but I guess that's just the main class. It also really helps to think of that line as a definition. Thank you again.